# Calculation of Degree of Dissociation from Ostwald's Dilution Law

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, ionic-compounds

A "weak" electrolyte, $\ce{A+B-}$, ionizes in solution as:

$$\ce{AB <=> A+ + B-}\tag{1}$$

$$  K_d =\dfrac{\ce{[A+][B-]}}{\ce{[AB]}}=\dfrac{(\alpha c_{0})(\alpha c_{0})}{(1-\alpha )c_{0}}=\dfrac{\alpha ^{2}}{1-\alpha }\cdot c_{0}\tag{2}$$

For a weak electrolyte the Degree of Dissociation, $\alpha$, is less than 1 and can be calculated using two different equations.

- Equation (2) can be rearranged to a quadratic equation which could be solved exactly with the standard quadratic formula.

$$ c_0 \cdot \alpha^2  + K_d\cdot \alpha -K_d = 0\tag{3}$$

$$\alpha = \dfrac{-K_d + \sqrt{K_d^2 - 4\cdot c_0 \cdot (-K_d) }}{2\cdot c_0} = \dfrac{-K_d + \sqrt{K_d^2 + 4\cdot c_0 \cdot K_d }}{2\cdot c_0}\tag{4}$$

- If we assume that there is little dissociation and that $\ce{[AB] \approx c_0}$ then $1- \alpha \approx 1$ and we obtain an approximate answer that is easier to calcualte:

$$  \alpha' \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_{0}}}\tag{5}$$

If equation (5) does not give the true value of the Degree of Dissociation. How do you know when it is good enough?

To make it clearer, say the approximate value from formula (5) is 0.15. That is not the true value of the degree of dissociation, but would the approximate solution be good enough?

Comment: I just edited the question to pinpoint what I think Limbo Productions was trying to ask. // User *Limbo Productions* if I missed interpreted your question please either edit the current version, or revert back to your original question.

Comment: @MaxW The flaw with the question is that it doesn't state what is known beforehand, or what would be regarded as a tolerable error. You provide a nice explanation of how the approximate $\alpha$ provides an upper bound on the true $\alpha$, and that is certainly useful. But otherwise this question seems pointless. If you know the values of $K_d$ and $c_0$ and of the tolerated error, then it is trivially found if the approximation is good enough. Maybe MFarooq is onto something regarding the point of the question, but we'll probably never know (and honestly I don't understand his explanation).

Comment: @BuckThorn - I took the OP's question to mean "in general". So for whatever problem comes along The tolerable error and $K_d/c_0$ would be for a particular known. Then for that particular problem, how is the OP to decide if the approximation is good enough? // My take away from MFarooq's point was the total effort to (1) make the approximate calculation and (2) to do a check is almost as great as the effort to solve the quadratic which gives the exact solution. So why bother with the approximation? Just solve the quadratic and be done with it.

Comment: @MaxW If that was MFarooq's point I completely agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asked a simple question to which [I gave a complex answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133107/22102). My daughter called such answers "Dad answers".

The OP essentially asked "If the dilute solution approximation for $\alpha$ is used when calculating, how do you know how good the approximation is?"

In his [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133127/22102) user porphyrin focused on the pertinent idea.

**Dilute Solution Approximation**

Now if we assume that $(1-\alpha) \approx 1$ meaning that very little of the compound dissociated, then we get the standard approximation, $\alpha'$:

$$  \alpha^{'} \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_{0}}}\tag{1}$$

**Exact Solution**

The equation below is an exact solution even though it doesn't allow $\alpha$ to be calculated directly. You would have to guess at $\alpha$ values and iterate until you found a solution.

$$\dfrac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1 - \alpha}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_{0}}}\tag{2}$$

**Estimated % Error**

Now let's calculate an estimated % error as:

$$\pu{Est \% Error} = 100 \times \dfrac{\dfrac{\alpha'}{\sqrt{1 - \alpha'}} - \alpha'}{\alpha'}\tag{3}$$

**Quadratic Solution**

The exact value of $\alpha$ can be calculated directly using a quadratic equation. The solution is given below.

$$\alpha = - \dfrac{K_d}{2\cdot c_0} + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{K_d}{2\cdot c_0}\right)^2 + \dfrac{K_d}{c_0}}\tag{4}$$

**Data Table**

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
(\alpha^{'})^2=K_d/c_0 & \alpha (quadratic) & approx & true\ \% \ error & est.\ \% \ error \\ \hline
1.00000000 & 0.61803399 & 1.00000000 & 61.80339887 &  \\ \hline
0.81000000 & 0.58192705 & 0.90000000 & 54.65856100 & 216.22776602 \\ \hline
0.64000000 & 0.54162637 & 0.80000000 & 47.70329614 & 123.60679775 \\ \hline
0.49000000 & 0.49663670 & 0.70000000 & 40.94810050 & 82.57418584 \\ \hline
0.36000000 & 0.44641839 & 0.60000000 & 34.40306509 & 58.11388301 \\ \hline
0.25000000 & 0.39038820 & 0.50000000 & 28.07764064 & 41.42135624 \\ \hline
0.16000000 & 0.32792156 & 0.40000000 & 21.98039027 & 29.09944487 \\ \hline
0.09000000 & 0.25835623 & 0.30000000 & 16.11874208 & 19.52286093 \\ \hline
0.04000000 & 0.18099751 & 0.20000000 & 10.49875621 & 11.80339887 \\ \hline
0.01000000 & 0.09512492 & 0.10000000 & 5.12492197 & 5.40925534 \\ \hline
0.00810000 & 0.08604108 & 0.09000000 & 4.60119879 & 4.82848367 \\ \hline
0.00640000 & 0.07686397 & 0.08000000 & 4.07996803 & 4.25720703 \\ \hline
0.00490000 & 0.06759286 & 0.07000000 & 3.56123125 & 3.69516947 \\ \hline
0.00360000 & 0.05822699 & 0.06000000 & 3.04498988 & 3.14212463 \\ \hline
0.00250000 & 0.04876562 & 0.05000000 & 2.53124512 & 2.59783521 \\ \hline
0.00160000 & 0.03920800 & 0.04000000 & 2.01999800 & 2.06207262 \\ \hline
0.00090000 & 0.02955337 & 0.03000000 & 1.51124937 & 1.53461651 \\ \hline
0.00040000 & 0.01980100 & 0.02000000 & 1.00499988 & 1.01525446 \\ \hline
0.00010000 & 0.00995012 & 0.01000000 & 0.50124999 & 0.50378153 \\ \hline
0.000001 & 0.0009995 & 0.00100000 & 0.05001250 & 0.05003753 \\ \hline
0.00000001 & 9.9995E-05 & 0.00010000 & 0.00500012 & 0.00500038 \\ \hline
1E-10 & 9.99995E-06 & 0.00001000 & 0.00050000 & 0.00050000 \\ \hline
\end{array}

So the Est % Error from equation (3) works quite well.

- When the Est % Error is 5% or less, $\alpha' \le 0.1$, the Est % Error is quite good.
- So for the approximate equation when $\alpha^{'} = 0.1$ you get 1 significant figure, 0.01 gets two significant figures and so on. The improvement doesn't continue forever of course - this is chemistry not math. To get three significant figures or more you'd have to be a fastidious experimenter.
- For the approximate equation when $\alpha' = 0.7$ the estimated error is 82.6% which is much too large, but an 82.6% error still tells you that the  approximation $\alpha^{'}$ is no good.
- To make user M. Farooq's point in another way, by the time you calculate the approximation from equation (1) and the Est % Error from equation (3), you've pretty much done enough work to calculate the exact answer using equation (4). So why bother with the approximation?

---

**EDIT** A comment by user *Buck Thorn* "I never thought about the usefulness of the estimate to bracket the true value" made me think.

**It turns out that we can bracket the true value $\alpha$ using a simple calculation of the approximate value $\alpha'$:**

$$\alpha'\cdot(1-\alpha') \lt \alpha < \alpha'\tag{5}$$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
(\alpha^{'})^2=K_d/c_0 & \alpha (quadratic) & \alpha'\cdot(1-\alpha') & \alpha' \\ \hline
1.0000000000 & 0.6180339887 & 0.0000000000 & 1.0000000000 \\ \hline
0.8100000000 & 0.5819270490 & 0.0900000000 & 0.9000000000 \\ \hline
0.6400000000 & 0.5416263691 & 0.1600000000 & 0.8000000000 \\ \hline
0.4900000000 & 0.4966367035 & 0.2100000000 & 0.7000000000 \\ \hline
0.3600000000 & 0.4464183905 & 0.2400000000 & 0.6000000000 \\ \hline
0.2500000000 & 0.3903882032 & 0.2500000000 & 0.5000000000 \\ \hline
0.1600000000 & 0.3279215611 & 0.2400000000 & 0.4000000000 \\ \hline
0.0900000000 & 0.2583562262 & 0.2100000000 & 0.3000000000 \\ \hline
0.0400000000 & 0.1809975124 & 0.1600000000 & 0.2000000000 \\ \hline
0.0100000000 & 0.0951249220 & 0.0900000000 & 0.1000000000 \\ \hline
0.0081000000 & 0.0860410789 & 0.0819000000 & 0.0900000000 \\ \hline
0.0064000000 & 0.0768639744 & 0.0736000000 & 0.0800000000 \\ \hline
0.0049000000 & 0.0675928619 & 0.0651000000 & 0.0700000000 \\ \hline
0.0036000000 & 0.0582269939 & 0.0564000000 & 0.0600000000 \\ \hline
0.0025000000 & 0.0487656226 & 0.0475000000 & 0.0500000000 \\ \hline
0.0016000000 & 0.0392079992 & 0.0384000000 & 0.0400000000 \\ \hline
0.0009000000 & 0.0295533748 & 0.0291000000 & 0.0300000000 \\ \hline
0.0004000000 & 0.0198010000 & 0.0196000000 & 0.0200000000 \\ \hline
1.000000E-04 & 0.0099501250 & 0.0099000000 & 0.0100000000 \\ \hline
1.000000E-06 & 0.0009995001 & 0.0009990000 & 0.0010000000 \\ \hline
1.000000E-08 & 0.0000999950 & 0.0000999900 & 0.0001000000 \\ \hline
1.000000E-10 & 9.999950E-06 & 9.999900E-06 & 0.0000100000 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: I was hoping for a more rigid explanation rooted in mathematics but I guess it has to come down to comparing values and noticing when they start to get reasonably close to each other. Less satisfying but I will take it. Thank you for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: @l1mbo - I'm befuddled as to what else you might want. It is easy to calculate the exact error. Let $\alpha$ be the solution from the quadratic solution, and $\alpha'$ be the solution from the approximation. Then: $$\pu{\% Error} = 100\times (\alpha' -\alpha)/\alpha)$$ But obviously if you're going to calculate $\alpha$, which is exact, why bother calculating $\alpha'$?

Comment: [I know this is 1.5 yrs late, I just happened to be going through my old posts on stack exchange so I stumbled on this, so I'll leave this here for anyone referring to this in the future] what I wanted was, in hindsight, extremely simple. The exact expression for $\alpha = - \dfrac{K_d}{2\cdot c_0} + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{K_d}{2\cdot c_0}\right)^2 + \dfrac{K_d}{c_0}}\tag{4}$ can be rewritten as function only of $\alpha'$ by replacing $\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}=\alpha'^2$.

Comment: Then, we can replace all $\alpha$ in the % error $= 100\times (\alpha' -\alpha)/\alpha)$ and thus % error can be written entirely as a function of $\alpha'$. Finally when we graph the error function we can see at what $\alpha'$ the error becomes greater than whatever value we see fit (5% error here) https://imgur.com/a/LsX7YlS This was 'more rigid' explanation I sought. (No idea why I struggled to figure out this rather elementary answer then)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative and simple estimation, assume $\alpha \lt\lt 1$ and expand $\displaystyle \frac{K_d}{c_0}=\frac{\alpha^2}{1-\alpha}$ to give $\displaystyle \frac{K_d}{c_0}=\alpha^2(1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\cdots)$ and compare the result to your approximation by adding correction terms.

Comment: Hmmm... You could a search and iteratively solve for $\alpha$ with that equation. However in order to solve for $\alpha$ directly you need some function of $K_d/c_0$. It would seem that using the first three terms would give you some idea of the error.

Comment: dah... Don't need the series. Let $\alpha = \sqrt{K_d/c_0}$ and compare $\alpha$ and $\alpha /\sqrt{1-\alpha}$ to get some idea of what the error is. It won't be exact, but in the ballpark.

Comment: yep:  that was what I thought.

Comment: @porphyrin, The student is talking about the  "*our formula derived with approximations will not give us the true value of the degree of dissociation*" ($sic$), he is wondering about the *validity* of the formula itself, not its quadratic approximations. **It is the definition of alpha that is the Achilles heel of this whole experiment in terms of conductance measurements.** I know how this experiment is taught in South Asia so I can feel what he is trying to ask although quite vaguely. We used make the students solve the whole quadratic equation, which is not a big deal.

Comment: The question was about how you could tell if the dilute approximation was any good. If $\alpha = \sqrt{K_d/c_0}$ then comparing $\alpha$ and $\alpha/\sqrt{1-\alpha}$ gives a good indication. // Solving the quadratic will always give the exact answer of course.

Comment: @M.Farooq Just to make everything clear, I thought I should specify what exactly I was told. We derive the simpler formula for the approximate value of alpha which should be used when alpha<0.1. But when solving questions alpha is an unknown so we don't know whether it is less than 0.1. To check this we put the values of the constants in the simpler approxformula. If alpha is <0.1 from this then we continue with the same. Otherwise we go back and solve the full quadratic. As to why I am emphasizing on solving problems instead of experiments is because I am studying for an engineering entrance.

Comment: @l1mbo, I can understand your background for test preparation. If your sole question is related to solving conductivity problems using Ostwald's dilution law, you should solve the full quadratic equation. Do you think you will have time to do all the Taylor series approximations in MCQs? If your question is about solving the dissociation constant problems in *general*, then it is a separate question. Post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Further elaboration to the answer. I recall teaching this experiment more than a decade ago (slightly rusty now). I think the approximation was is not mathematical (A) or (B), as one *has* to solve the entire quadratic equation by all means.

$$ \alpha = \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d\cdot (1-\alpha )}{c}}\tag{A}$$

and

$$ \alpha^{'} \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c}}\tag{B}$$

As one can see in equation (A) and (B), K$_d$ has a very strong dependence on concentration of acetic acid taken for measurement. Certainly, during the experiment we cannot take an infinitely dilute weak acid solution, so we do the experiment with sufficiently dilute acid but of finite concentration. The fundamental or *key* issue is the way 
$\alpha$ is defined. It is given by

$$ \alpha = \frac{\Lambda}{\Lambda_0}\tag{C}$$

where the numerator indicates the conductivity at concentration $c$ and the denominator shows the conductivity at zero concentration.

The accuracy of the dissociation constant is dependent on this *measurement* and the validity of the equation (C). This expression is *not* valid for strong electrolytes (hence strong bases and acids are not used for dissociation constant experiments)

So apparently, the student is confused why only weak electrolytes can be measured by conductivity: The reason is the validity of equation (C).

He also assumes that only conductivity experiment is used to determine the dissociation constant of an acid and base. Since we are determining Kd from a conductivity measurement, how do we know beforehand that the acid/base is weak. This circular argument is not true at all. The weakness of an acid or a base in water is easily determined by a simple pH measurement. For example, pH of 0.01 M acetic acid is higher than pH of 0.01 M HCl, which indicates that acetic acid is not fully dissociated. Conductivity is not the only way to determine the dissociation constants, it is one of the possible ways.

Comment: Granted other ways may exist, but that doesn't mean we do not determine dissociation solely on the basis discussed above.

Comment: Equation (B) is the [typical shortcut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_dilution#Derivation) to an answer assuming that there is is little disassociation. If $\alpha^{'} \le 0.1$ the answer will be within 5%, if  If $\alpha^{'} \le 0.010$ the answer will be within 1%. So you don't *always* have to solve the quadratic, though the quadratic will always give the exact answer.

Comment: " only weak acids or bases can be measured by conductivity measurements." Isn't the point that you don't have to worry (as much) about activity coefficients in weakly dissociating electrolytes? In any case, I find the last paragraph confusing.

Comment: I was referring to the the determination of dissociation constants by conductivity measurements. Only relatively weak acids or bases can be employed for such experiments. I have tried to clarify the the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

> *I rearranged the answer and moved the equations around. However I kept the original numbering so that the comments make sense.*

Consider a binary electrolyte AB which dissociates reversibly into A+ and B− ions with a nominal concentration of $c_0$. Ostwald noted that the law of mass action can be applied to such systems as dissociating electrolytes. The equilibrium state is represented by the equation:

$$\ce{AB <=> A+ + B^-}\tag{1}$$

If $\alpha$ is the fraction of dissociated electrolyte, then $\alpha \cdot c_0$ is the concentration of each ionic species. $(1-\alpha)$ must, therefore be the fraction of undissociated electrolyte, and $(1- \alpha )\cdot c_0$ the concentration of same. The dissociation constant may therefore be given as

$$  K_d =\dfrac{\ce{[A+][B-]}}{\ce{[AB]}}=\dfrac{(\alpha c_{0})(\alpha c_{0})}{(1-\alpha )c_{0}}=\dfrac{\alpha ^{2}}{1-\alpha }\cdot c_{0}\tag{2}$$

So far I've copied the Wikipedia article on the [Law of dilution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_dilution) almost exactly. Now I'll depart that derivation.

From equation (2) let's start with:
  $$  K_d = \dfrac{\alpha ^{2}}{1-\alpha }\cdot c_{0}\tag{3}$$

**Dilute Solution Approximation**

now if we assume that $(1-\alpha) \approx 1$ meaning that very little of the compound dissociated, then we get the standard approximation, $\alpha'$:

$$  \alpha^{'} \approx \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_{0}}}\tag{6}$$

**Exact Solution - Odd Form**

Now let's play around with Equation (3) to form an exact solution in an odd sort of form.

$$  \alpha^2 = \dfrac{K_d\cdot (1-\alpha )}{c_{0}}\tag{4}$$

and solving for the square root:

$$  \alpha = \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_{0}}\cdot (1-\alpha )}\tag{5}$$

Now Equation (5) is in an odd form, but it is exact. Knowing $K_d/c_0$ one could guess at values of $\alpha$ until a value was found that would satisfy the equation.

Remember that we're looking for values of $K_c/c_0 << 1$. Comparing equations (6) and (5) it is obvious to the casual observer that equation (6)  must always give a value that is larger than equation (5). Hence if $ 1 \gg \alpha^{'}$ then $ 1 \gg \alpha^{'} \gt \alpha$

**Exact Solution - Exact Quadratic Solution**

Equation(5) is in the wrong form to directly solve for $\alpha$ of course. So let's go back to equation (3) and rearrange to a reduced quadratic equation which could be solved with the standard quadratic formula.

$$ \alpha^2 +\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}\cdot \alpha -\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}= 0\tag{7}$$

$$\alpha = - \dfrac{K_d}{2\cdot c_0} + \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{K_d}{2\cdot c_0}\right)^2 + \dfrac{K_d}{c_0}}\tag{8}$$

**Data Table**

Now for various $K_d/c_0$ values let's calculate the approximate solution, the exact solution, and the % Error.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\dfrac{K_d}{c_0} & Approximation & Quadratic & \% Error \\
& Equation (6) & Equation (8) &  \\ \hline
1.00000000 & 1.00000000 & 0.618034 & 61.803399 \\ \hline
0.81000000 & 0.90000000 & 0.581927 & 54.658561 \\ \hline
0.64000000 & 0.80000000 & 0.541626 & 47.703296 \\ \hline
0.49000000 & 0.70000000 & 0.496637 & 40.948101 \\ \hline
0.36000000 & 0.60000000 & 0.446418 & 34.403065 \\ \hline
0.25000000 & 0.50000000 & 0.390388 & 28.077641 \\ \hline
0.16000000 & 0.40000000 & 0.327922 & 21.980390 \\ \hline
0.09000000 & 0.30000000 & 0.258356 & 16.118742 \\ \hline
0.04000000 & 0.20000000 & 0.180998 & 10.498756 \\ \hline
0.02647076 & 0.16269836 & 0.150000 & 8.465257 \\ \hline
0.02250000 & 0.15000000 & 0.139171 & 7.780856 \\ \hline
0.01000000 & 0.10000000 & 0.095125 & 5.124922 \\ \hline
0.00010000 & 0.01000000 & 0.009950125 & 0.501249992 \\ \hline
1.000000E-06 & 0.00100000 & 9.995001E-04 & 5.001250E-02 \\ \hline
1.000000E-08 &  0.00010000 & 9.999500E-05 & 5.000125E-03 \\ \hline
1.000000E-10 & 0.00001000 & 9.999950E-06 &  5.000013E-04 \\ \hline
1.000000E-12 & 0.00000100 & 9.999995E-07 & 5.000001E-05\\ \hline
\end{array}

(1) So for this equation when the approximate amount of dissociation is 0.1 you get 1 significant figure, 0.01 gets two significant figures and so on. The improvement doesn't continue forever of course this is chemistry not math. To get three significant figures you'd have to be a fastidious experimenter.

(2) Notice that the exact quadratic solution is always lower than the approximate solution.

(3) The OP asked how the exact solution of 0.15 dissociation would compare with the approximate solution. From the table the corresponding value is about 0.163, an error of about +8.5%.

**Exact Enough Solution - Using Linear Series Solution**

In case the hand-waving argument above didn't persuade you that the approximate solution is always bigger that the exact solution, let's explore a solution using a series where an increasing number of terms could be used to get a solution as exact as desired.

Rearranging equation (8), an exact equation, by pulling out a $\sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}}$ term:

\begin{align*}
\alpha 
&= \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}} \left( \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0} + 1} - \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0}} \right)\tag{9} \\
&= \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}} \left( \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0} + 1} - \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0}} \right)\cdot \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0} + 1} + \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0}}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0} + 1} + \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0}}} \right)\tag{10} \\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{c_0}}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0} + 1} + \sqrt{\dfrac{K_d}{4\cdot c_0}}} \tag{11}
\end{align*}

Now, using the Taylor series for the denominator yields an *approximation*, which is quite good.  (Many thanks to user [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3659153/23782) on the 
Mathematics site for the heavy lifting here...)

$${\sqrt{\dfrac{K_c/c_0}{4} + 1} +\sqrt{\dfrac{K_c/c_0}{4}} }=1+\frac{\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{2}+\frac{K_c/c_0}{8}+O\left((K_c/c_0)^{2}\right)\tag{12}$$ which makes

$$\alpha^{"} \approx \frac {\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{2}+\frac{K_c/c_0}{8}}\tag{13}$$

Obviously the more terms the better the approximation, but three terms is good enough for anything that we chemists would do. Again remember that we're solving for dilute solutions where $K_c/c_0 \ll 1$. Also notice that all the terms are positive so the more terms used, the smaller the value of the dissociation fraction.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
K_c/c_0 & Quadratic & \sqrt{K_c/c_0} & \frac {\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{2}} & \frac {\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{K_c/c_0}}{2} + \frac{K_c/c_0}{8}} \\ \hline
1 & 0.61803399 & 1.00000000 & 0.66666667 & 0.61538462 \\ \hline
0.81 & 0.58192705 & 0.90000000 & 0.62068966 & 0.58017728 \\ \hline
0.64 & 0.54162637 & 0.80000000 & 0.57142857 & 0.54054054 \\ \hline
0.49 & 0.49663670 & 0.70000000 & 0.51851852 & 0.49601417 \\ \hline
0.36 & 0.44641839 & 0.60000000 & 0.46153846 & 0.44609665 \\ \hline
0.25 & 0.39038820 & 0.50000000 & 0.40000000 & 0.39024390 \\ \hline
0.16 & 0.32792156 & 0.40000000 & 0.33333333 & 0.32786885 \\ \hline
0.09 & 0.25835623 & 0.30000000 & 0.26086957 & 0.25834230 \\ \hline
0.04 & 0.18099751 & 0.20000000 & 0.18181818 & 0.18099548 \\ \hline
0.01 & 0.09512492 & 0.10000000 & 0.09523810 & 0.09512485 \\ \hline
0.0001 & 0.00995012 & 0.01000000 & 0.00995025 & 0.00995012 \\ \hline
0.000001 & 0.00099950 & 0.00100000 & 0.00099950 & 0.00099950 \\ \hline
0.00000001 & 0.00010000 & 0.00010000 & 0.00010000 & 0.00010000 \\ \hline
1E-10 & 0.00001000 & 0.00001000 & 0.00001000 & 0.00001000 \\ \hline
1E-12 & 0.00000100 & 0.00000100 & 0.00000100 & 0.00000100 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: I am confused, what is the conceptual difference between equation (2) (3) and (8)? It seems like a circular argument.

Comment: @M.Farooq - It is the difference between equations 5 and 6 that is important. Note *alpha* and *alpha-prime* are calculated and that alpha-prime > alpha always.

Comment: I still don't understand how the central question of why we think it's okay to use _alpha- prime_ which we derive through an approximation instead of _alpha_ to judge whether the approximation was correct in the first place

Comment: @LimboProductions, read **both** answers carefully especially the last paragraph of my answer. You have a misconception regarding this circular argument.

Comment: @LimboProductions - I agree that I need to make the argument clearer. The gist is that the approximation assumes that little dissociation has occurred so the fraction dissociated is much less than 1. So if the approximation says that 1% has dissociated, the exact solution will show that slightly less has. So it is reasonable to use the approximate value to test the hypothesis.

Comment: @MaxW, Then if the approximation shows that dissociation is, say, 13%, but as the real value will be lesser, let's say it is 8-9%. Here, in reality we can use the approximation but we would think otherwise. (I am assuming we have no way to calculate how much lower would the actual value be, or even an ballpark estimate, so correct me if I am wrong in assuming this)

Comment: @LimboProductions - I'm trying to work out a series expansion now for the exact expression. Also the exact value is easily obtained by solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: Ok, I've done a major revision to the answer, Hopefully the revised version is easier to understand.

Comment: +1 I found this a useful answer, I never thought about the usefulness of the estimate to bracket the true value. But I do wonder what is the usefulness of the final exercise. Eq 11 is certainly not an improvement over Eq 9 in terms of simplicity.

Comment: @BuckThorn - The point of the last section was to go from equation (8) which is the quadratic solution to equation (13) - never intended to stop at equation (9). Even with just two terms in the denominator equation (13)  works very well for $K_d/c_0 < 0.5$. Using all three terms in equation (13) gives you near perfect values up to $K_d/c_0 = 1$.

Comment: I think you changed the equation labels. My question remains: the final series expansion does not seem an advantage  over the exact solution (it seems even more complicated to compute). And the advantage of the simplified formula is that you can quickly evaluate it in your calculator or even your head (back when people knew how to estimate square roots in their heads). The advantage is more or less null in our day of broadly available computing power.

Comment: @BuckThorn - I did number the last two equations, otherwise the equations have kept their numbering. In one of the revisions I did move the equations around, but I kept the numbering. // I added a [second answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133144/22102) which is much more the the OP's question. My final point there was if you're going to use the approximation, then check the error bound, why not just use the quadratic to begin with since it gives the *exact* answer for a pittance of extra work.